# Dynamic if/else statement with jQuery and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

So I'm trying to style a `<textarea>` tag to highlight when it has more than one character typed in. (For a contact form). When someone is filling out the form, the fields will all highlight green to let them know its valid. I'm very new to JS and jQuery in general but I'm pretty sure this is supossed to work. I can use the `$('#message').addClass('valid')` by itself and it will apply the class, but when I add the if/else statement, nothing works. Here is the script

```
\\ Begin Highlight Code
var $messageval = $('#message').val()
    if ($messageval.length != 0 ){
     $('#message').addClass('valid');
    }
    else ($messageval.length = 0 ){
      $('#message').removeClass('valid');
    }
  });
```

I've been googling for hours and I can't find anything to dynamically add and remove classes based on a text length variable.

Thanks

Comment: That's not a valid comment in the beginning...

Comment: else does not have parameters to check. Even if it did, that condition would always be true. Use == not just =. you are missing a semi colon on the var and this is happening on what - page load? You should place this in a keyup listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `else if`

```
 if ($messageval.length != 0 ){
     $(this).addClass('valid');
    }
    else if($messageval.length == 0 ){ //<-- Here
      $('#message').removeClass('valid');
    }
```

Basically you can just have

```
   if ($messageval.length != 0 ){
     $('#message').addClass('valid');
    }
    else { //<-- Here
      $('#message').removeClass('valid');
    }
```

I guess this is what you are looking for:-

```
  $(function(){
   $('#message').on('keyup', function () {
    var $messageval = $.trim($(this).val()); //$.trim here  to avoid whitespace preventing validation.

    if ($messageval.length != 0) {
        $(this).addClass('valid'); //this here represent the textarea dom element, and $(this) is the jquery wrapper.
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('valid');
    }
  });
 });
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m9gm/)

Comment: I'll plus if you add the event listener for keyup

Comment: I know I closed this, but how would I add the class if text is present on page load? If you refresh with text in the box, the class isn't applied, even on `keyup`

Comment: if you want to apply on page load you can just put the conditon out side of any function under document ready. But if you think it is always going to be there then put the class valid to the textarea markup itself, or when you assign value to the textarea you can add this class as well.

Comment: If you add text to the form and refresh the form isn't cleared. I just want to check to see if there is text on load in case of a refresh

Comment: you can keep the condition of adding the style class using on change event and just trigger the change event while the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#message").keyup(function(){
        var messageval = $('#message').val();
        if (messageval.length > 1) {
            $('#message').addClass('valid');
        } else {
            $('#message').removeClass('valid');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. [Link to site](http://www.daronspence.com/newsite)

Comment: What does it mean - "it didn't work"? A little man crawled out of the computer and told you so?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#message').trigger('change');//if you initially want to check the textarea

        $('#message').on('change', function(){
        var $messageval = $(this).val();
        if ($messageval.length != 0 ){
         if (!$(this).hasClass("valid")) {
            $(this).addClass("valid");
          }
        }
        else ($messageval.length == 0 ){
          if ($(this).hasClass("valid")) {
             $(this).removeClass("valid");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Cheers!